# queryIntentActivities method returns empty List for API level 23 (Marshmallow) and below

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I am trying to check for capabilities of all installed apps to handle "Intent.ACTION_SENDTO" for which I am using the following snippet of code.

```
        Intent mailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        infos = manager.queryIntentActivities(mailIntent, 0);
        Log.i(TAG,"number of apps that can hadle ACTION_SENDTO "+infos.size());
        if(infos.size()>0){
            //do actions
        }
```

This snippet seemed to give proper result for Android N and above but for API level 23 and below this snippet gives me emptyList. however the interesting part is even for devices of API level 23 and below the Intent.ACTION_SENDTO is handled by mail apps and the email application is launced when i run the below snippet

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,Uri.parse(UIConstants.EMAIL_URI+mEmail));
                    startActivity(i);
```

Can anyone help me understand why `infos.size()` retuns 0 in my first snippet for API level 23 and below

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if you can handle the intent with:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "No Intent available to handle action");
}
```

Comment: Tried to check with above snippet, but not working. Any other ways to check if the apps can handle intent

Answer (score 0):

Setting data should do the trick.
`mailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));`